# How do I setup a USB drive as a boot drive on Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: usb, bootloader

I am somewhat new to Raspberry Pi.

I would like to make the 5 TB WD My Book USB drive the boot drive with the `Raspberry Pi OS FULL (32-Bit)` image. If I use the `Raspberry Pi Imager` to configure the USB Drive, I encounter an error on the firstboot because of insufficient privileges to create partitions. I have also noticed that the `Raspberry Pi Imager` converts the drive to MBR. This renders 3TB of the drive unusable.

I am going to be using some development tools that only work when installed to the boot drive.

> Thus far, I have had no luck what-so-ever on using a 5 TB GPT drive
> as a boot drive. I can use it as a data drive.
>
> Most of the problems are partition issues.

### What I have tried

#### Imager

> ```
> When the the `Imager` on the WD My_Book 5 TB drive (with no
> no partitions); an attempt is made during the firstboot to 
> resize the /dev/sda2. This fails and leaves the drive in an 
> error state. The error that appears in GParted is:
>
> Superblock checksum does not match the superblock while trying
> to open /dev/sda2. Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
> ```

1. Issued the following command:

```
$sudo su - root
```

2. Removed all existing partitions from the USB drive in `GParted`.
3. Started the `Imager`.
4. Set the following options:

```
Operating System: RASPBERRY PI OS FULL (32-BiT)
Storage: WD MY_BOOK
```

5. `Imager` successfully writes and verifies to the USB Drive. The following message appears:

> ```
> Write Successful
>
> Raspberry Pi OS Full (32-bit) has 
> been written to WD My_Book_25EE.
>
> You can now remove the SD card from
> the reader
> ```

6. Removed the SD Card and Clicked OK.
7. Re-booted the Raspberry Pi.

> The Raspberry Pi endlessly cycles between:
> Trying Boot Mode USB-MSD
> and
> Trying Boot Mode SD
>
> OR
>
> ```
> Subsequent re-boot produces the following error:
>
> Failed running firstboot:
> Partition table resize of the root partition (/dev/sda2)
> failed
> ```

#### Manually define Partitions

I have worked through partitioning and formatting the partitions of the 5 TB USB drive. My steps are below.

1. Unmounted the drive from the Raspberry Pi `File Manager`.
2. Opened a terminal and started a `parted` session.

```
$ sudo parted
```

3. Selected the `/dev/sda` drive to partition.

```
(parted) select /dev/sda
```

4. Created a GPT partition table.

```
(parted) mklabel gpt
```

5. Created new partitions on the drive.

```
(parted) mkpart os fat32 0gb 750gb
(parted) mkpart dev-ntfs 750gb 50%
(parted) mkpart dev-ext4 50% 100%
```

6. Exited `parted`.

```
(parted) q
```

7. Formatted the new partitions.

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -L dev-ntfs -Q /dev/sda2
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -L dev-ext4 /dev/sda3
```

8. Powered down the Raspberry Pi and restarted.
9. Temporarily remounted the partitions under `/mnt`.

```
$ cd /mnt
$ sudo mkdir dev-ntfs
$ sudo mkdir dev-ext4
```

10. Temporarily mount the partitions.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/dev-ntfs
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/dev-ext4
```

11. Obtain the `PARTUUID` for the new partitions.

```
$ sudo blkid
```

12. At a stand-still until I can find a way to install the OS on the USB.

#### rpi-clone

1. Unmounted and deleted all partitions from the USB Drive in `GParted`.
2. Tried using `rpi-clone` as per https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone
3. Set the boot-order in `raspi-config`.
4. This clones the SD-Card to the USB but renders the majority of the USB drive unallocated and unusable.

> The Raspberry Pi will not boot from the USB drive.

## Test Case with 128 GB USB (This Works)

As a test case I setup a 128 GB USB stick by using the `Raspberry Pi Imager`.

> ```
> This works.
> ```

1. Boot the Raspberry Pi 4B from an SD Card.
2. Make sure the Raspberry Pi 4B is up-to-date.

```
$ sudo apt-get ugrade -y
$ sudo rpt-eeprom-update
```

> ```
> My Raspberry Pi 4B was already up-to-date from attempts with
> the GPT drive.
> ```

3. Plug the 128 GB stick into a USB3 port.
4. Use the `Raspberry Pi Imager` to burn the OS onto the 128 GB USB stick.
5. When the imager completes the verify of the write to the 128 GB USB, shut down the Raspberry Pi 4B.
6. Take the SD-Card out of the Raspberry Pi 4B.
7. Power the Raspberry Pi 4B on.

### Questions

1. I would like to setup a USB GPT drive with desired partitions.

> ```
>  I have setup partitions on the USB GPT that ensures all 
>  partitions are < 2 TB and fat32.
> ```

I would like to:

- Setup the desired partitions manually on a USB GPT drive with a predefined `boot` partition.
- Copy the `boot` from a working SD-Card to the predefined USB GPT drive.
- Boot from the GPT USB Drive and by-pass the automatic resize of the GPT USB Drive during firstboot (or any boot).

Comment: *Saved changes to the /etc/fstab file.* you probably did this wrong - what changes?

Comment: *This renders 3 TB of the USB drive as unreachable.* - sure, but you can increase the size of partition 2, and add a new partitions without losing anything - note, you'd end up with partition order being FAT/EXT4/NTFS of course

Comment: Jeromanda - I updated the notes above. The Raspberry Pi 4B is automatically mounting the partitions without any changes to `/etc/fstab`. I need to do some research to determine where the partitions are actually set. If I open `/etc/fstab', no new lines for the two new USB drive partitions are there. This must have been changed.

Comment: This is not weird at all. Think: How can a file on a filesystem (such as `/etc/fstab`) determine where the root fs is?  Do we check all accessible filesystems?  What if there is an `/etc/fstab` on all of them and they conflict? **Like any linux system, the root fs is determined by the kernel command line,** generally provided by the bootloader (which in the case of the Pi, is read from the `cmdline.txt` file on the boot partition).  You should consult the official documentation when doing this kind of thing: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html

Comment: You may need to alter/update the EEPROM in order to boot from GPT.  I believe `raspi-config` has an option for this, but I have not checked.   The GUI imager cannot do that (while it could write something to the image to run on first boot and do it, there is an obvious chicken and egg problem there).

Comment: goldilicks: Good points. One of my questions is: where is the configuration of the USB partitions physically stored? I will checkout the `cmdline.txt`. There are additional issues with the GUI imager: for example, I would like use partitions that I have setup on the USB drive (and not have them overwritten by the imager).

Comment: I have found some bits and pieces on booting a Raspberry Pi 4B from a GPT drive - but nothing that looks definitive.

Comment: I have never used the GUI imager, or USB boot, but I notice in a screenshot somewhere it is pretty explicit in the imager that booting from USB is something that is set by reflashing the EEPROM.  I think you have been through this, but point being, there is no file somewhere you can find/copy those settings from.  It is akin to the BIOS settings on a more normal computer.   WRT *"I am going to be using some development tools that only work when installed to the boot drive"*, perhaps you should approach this more like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479):

Comment: ...Why do these tools require the "boot drive", and what exactly do you mean by "boot *drive*"?  They are installed on **a filesystem**, correct?  The boot *partition* (and the *filesystem* it contains) on a Pi, regardless of what kind of drive it is on, cannot possibly be used for this, so presumably they are installed to the *root filesystem*, which is in the other partition and does not need to be on the same device.  Ie., **Why do you believe you cannot do this by booting from an SD card, with the root filesystem set to a USB device**?

Comment: I don't think re-flashing EEPROM is required any more.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tTFgrOCsig&t=47s

Comment: I am creating a Pi as a development box for a proprietary data acquisition project. The development tools have to be on the boot device. I think this is a real limitation. I can use the USB GPT device as a data drive and boot from the SD card.  The SD card has insufficient space for the development tools. Since external circuitry is involved, debugging over SSH is very difficult.

Comment: Please add details about the development tools and maybe a link to documentation to your question. What is the size requirement? Why don't you use an SD card with more memory?

Answer (score 1):

The imager takes a compressed .img file and overlays what is on your target drive.  The .img file is the DOS MBR; some space; the VFAT32 partition (containing the kernel and cmdline.txt that will later be mounted at /boot); possibly some space; and then the root partition (mounted, of course, at '/').

Since the .img file is of an image of a DOS MBR drive, not a GPT drive, it can only support a ~2TB drive. And, if your drive was formatted (or more likely came formatted) as GPT, there is a backup partition table at the end of the drive. If you use the "imager", *many* things will then complain that the GPT drive is corrupted (it sees the backup partition table at the end of the drive, and sees the GPT partition table at the front of the drive has been "wiped out".

As GPT partition tables are checksummed, it is hard to use the old ways (imager) of creating a bootable drive. (Way out of my pay-grade.)

I have a cheap utility written in 'C' on github, https://github.com/tommylovell/raspberry-split, that breaks out the 'boot' and 'root' partitions as separate files so they can be mounted on loopback and rsynced to their destination filesystems. I manually (well, by script) create target filesystems as the first two partitions on the GPT drive; rsync files to where they should be; edit cmdline.txt and fstab so they are correct; and the drive is now bootable on a Pi4B.

Unfortunately, everything I have runs under Ubuntu Linux, so it could be run on the Pi -- slowly... But, it is actually a lot simpler than it sounds.

Sorry this answer is so long.  If you want, I can post the script I use as an addendum to this answer.